# How to split optional arguments

Tags: xparse

With commands such as `\usepackage`, all options can be given within the same pair of square brackets, using only commas as delimiters.

I'd like to achieve the same thing, here for example with the `\coolphase` command, i.e. write `\coolphase[-77,2]{nab}`.

How do I do it ?

I tried this but it doesn't work :

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\coolphasesplit}{>{\SplitArgument{4}{,}}o}{\coolphase#1}
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\NewDocumentCommand{\coolphase}{
    O{-58}
    O{0}
    O{8}
    O{150}
    O{110}
    m}
{\draw[dotted,thick]([xshift=#1pt,yshift=#2pt]#6) arc[start angle=#4,end angle=#5,radius=#3cm];}


\begin{document}
    
\begin{forest}
    [ASP[\textit{subject}][Asp 
    [asp][POL
    [AdvP[\textit{non},roof]][Pol
    [pol, name=nab][aP
    [~][a′
    [a][root]]]]]]]
    \coolphase[-77][2]{nab}
\end{forest}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be better from a UX perspective to supply the optional arguments as a set of keys. Your current setup *requires* the first optional arguments to be specified in order to specify other optional arguments. For example, you **need** to specify `<1>` in order to specify `<2>` in `\coolphase[<1>][<2>]{...}`. However, a key-value approach would allow you to `\coolphase[yshift=<2>]{...}` without having to specify `xshift`. Of course, if you're the only user, then UX is probably not a consideration...

Comment: Would be awesome, no idea how to achieve this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might be possible to do it without `\ExplSyntaxOn`, but it would be really cumbersome.

With `\SplitArgument{4}{,}`, the missing values are replaced by the special `-NoValue-` string, that can be tested with `\tl_if_novalue:nTF`.

We need to expand the test before `\__krebs_coolphase:nnnnnn` sees the actual arguments.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

% this uses TikZ so it cannot go in \ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\coolphaseaux}{mmmmmm}{%
  \draw[dotted,thick]([xshift=#1pt,yshift=#2pt]#6) arc[start angle=#4,end angle=#5,radius=#3cm];
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\coolphase}{>{\SplitArgument{4}{,}}om}
 {
  \krebs_coolphase:nnnnnn #1{#2}
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \krebs_coolphase:nnnnnn
 {
  \__krebs_coolphase:eeeeen
   { \tl_if_novalue:nTF { #1 } { -58 } { #1 } }
   { \tl_if_novalue:nTF { #2 } {   0 } { #2 } }
   { \tl_if_novalue:nTF { #3 } {   8 } { #3 } }
   { \tl_if_novalue:nTF { #4 } { 150 } { #4 } }
   { \tl_if_novalue:nTF { #5 } { 110 } { #5 } }
   { #6 }
 }
% make an internal version of \coolphaseaux
\cs_set_eq:NN \__krebs_coolphase:nnnnnn \coolphaseaux
% generate the needed variant
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__krebs_coolphase:nnnnnn { eeeee }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    
\begin{forest}
    [ASP[\textit{subject}][Asp 
    [asp][POL
    [AdvP[\textit{non},roof]][Pol
    [pol, name=nab][aP
    [~][a'
    [a][root]]]]]]]
    \coolphase[-77,2]{nab}
\end{forest}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, it is much better if you use a key-value system, so you need not remember the precise order of the options.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

% this uses TikZ so it cannot go in \ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\coolphaseaux}{mmmmmm}{%
  \draw[dotted,thick]([xshift=#1pt,yshift=#2pt]#6) arc[start angle=#4,end angle=#5,radius=#3cm];
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\coolphase}{O{}m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { krebs/coolphase } { #1 }
  \krebs_coolphase:VVVVVn
   \l__krebs_coolphase_x_tl
   \l__krebs_coolphase_y_tl
   \l__krebs_coolphase_sa_tl
   \l__krebs_coolphase_ea_tl
   \l__krebs_coolphase_r_tl
   {#2}
   \group_end:
 }
\keys_define:nn { krebs/coolphase }
 {
  x  .tl_set:N = \l__krebs_coolphase_x_tl,
  y  .tl_set:N = \l__krebs_coolphase_y_tl,
  sa .tl_set:N = \l__krebs_coolphase_sa_tl,
  ea .tl_set:N = \l__krebs_coolphase_ea_tl,
  r  .tl_set:N = \l__krebs_coolphase_r_tl,
  x  .initial:n = -58,
  y  .initial:n = 0,
  sa .initial:n = 8,
  ea .initial:n = 150,
  r  .initial:n = 110,
 }
% make an internal version of \coolphaseaux
\cs_set_eq:NN \krebs_coolphase:nnnnnn \coolphaseaux
% generate the needed variant
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \krebs_coolphase:nnnnnn { VVVVV }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    
\begin{forest}
    [ASP[\textit{subject}][Asp 
    [asp][POL
    [AdvP[\textit{non},roof]][Pol
    [pol, name=nab][aP
    [~][a'
    [a][root]]]]]]]
    \coolphase[x=-77,y=2]{nab}
\end{forest}
    
\end{document}
```

You could pass `r=110,sa=150,x=-77,ea=110,y=2`, say, without worrying about the right order.

Comment: @VincentKrebs Do you plan to use also decimal values or just integers?

Comment: Your first code has a bug due to the (very unfortunate) design decision to not use an argument processor on the no-value-flag, your optional argument is actually mandatory this way or else `\coolphase` will expand to `\krebs_coolphase:nnnnnn -NoValue- {#2}`.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is possible using TeX. Something like this should work:

```
\def\coolphase(#1, #2){
    %function definition
}
```

Comment: This should be the case for `[`...`]` as well, but it doesn't make it optional.

Answer (score 1):

Using PythonTeX:

```
%! TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pythontex}

\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\begin{pycode}
def coolphase(opt_parts, arg2):
    opt_default=[-58, 0, 8, 150, 110]
    if len(opt_parts)>len(opt_default):
        raise ValueError("Too many arguments")
    opt_parts+=opt_default[len(opt_parts):]  # fill in default arguments.
    # Now opt_parts = [77, 2, 8, 150, 110]

    print(
            r"\draw[dotted,thick]([xshift={xshift}pt,yshift={yshift}pt]{extra}) arc[start angle={start_angle},end angle={end_angle},radius={radius}cm];"
            .format(
                xshift=opt_parts[0],
                yshift=opt_parts[1],
                radius=opt_parts[2],
                start_angle=opt_parts[3],
                end_angle=opt_parts[4],
                extra=arg2
                )
            )
\end{pycode}
\NewDocumentCommand\coolphase{om}{\pyc{coolphase([#1],r"""#2""")}}


\begin{document}
    
\begin{forest}
    [ASP[\textit{subject}][Asp 
    [asp][POL
    [AdvP[\textit{non},roof]][Pol
    [pol, name=nab][aP
    [~][a′
    [a][root]]]]]]]
    \coolphase[-77,2]{nab}
\end{forest}
    
\end{document}
```

Output is as you expect.

Comment: or [use my pythonimmediate package](https://gist.github.com/user202729/d524f243f5f5e2c171794e5150c25bbb). In this case there's not much difference (my package only require one compilation and works even if there's triple quote inside the second argument)