# Program a key/value-style optional argument (expl3 command) such that relative values must be used

Tags: expl3, xparse

Thanks to `egreg`'s answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/669975/262813) I created a command involving a key/value-style splitted optional argument.

The `expl3` syntax allows to indicate the default value for each key.

The default values in my optional argument are, respectively:

```
    x.initial:n = -74,
    y.initial:n = 0,
    sa.initial:n = 8,
    ea.initial:n = 150,
    r.initial:n = 110,
```

I was wondering whether it would be possible to program the command in such a way that I will be able to use relative values when calling it, i.e. if the default value is 150 and you need a value of 150.1, you would just indicate a relative value of 0.1.

Thanks to this, I won't have to remember the default value, but instead I only need to think about the shift relative to what I visually consider to be a standard setting.

The original command given in the MWE is:

```
\coolphase[x=-72,y=2,sa=8.1,ea=152.3,r=109.9]{nab}
```

Now, I want to be able to input the following instead:

```
\coolphase[x=2,y=2,sa=0.1,ea=2.3,r=-0.1]{nab}
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}


\NewDocumentCommand{\coolphaseaux}{mmmmmm}{%
    \draw[dotted,thick]([xshift=#1pt,yshift=#2pt]#6) arc[start angle=#4,end angle=#5,radius=#3cm];
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\coolphase}{O{}m}
{
    \group_begin:
    \keys_set:nn{coolphase}{#1}
    \coolphase:VVVVVn
    \coolphase_x
    \coolphase_y
    \coolphase_sa
    \coolphase_ea
    \coolphase_r
    {#2}
    \group_end:
}

\keys_define:nn{coolphase}
{
    x.tl_set:N = \coolphase_x,
    y.tl_set:N = \coolphase_y,
    sa.tl_set:N = \coolphase_sa,
    ea.tl_set:N = \coolphase_ea,
    r.tl_set:N = \coolphase_r,
    x.initial:n = -74,
    y.initial:n = 0,
    sa.initial:n = 8,
    ea.initial:n = 150,
    r.initial:n = 110,
}

\cs_set_eq:NN\coolphase:nnnnnn\coolphaseaux
\cs_generate_variant:Nn\coolphase:nnnnnn{VVVVV}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
    
    \begin{forest}
        [ASP[\textit{subject}][Asp 
        [asp][POL
        [AdvP[\textit{non},roof]][Pol
        [pol, name=nab][aP
        [~][a'
        [a][root]]]]]]]
        \coolphase[x=-75,y=2,ea=150.1,sa=8.1,r=109.9]{nab}
    \end{forest}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps simply change `xshift=#1pt` in the definition of `\coolphaseaux` to `xshift=(-74+#1)*1pt` and `x.initial:n=-74` to `x.initial:n=0`? Similarly for the other parameters

Comment: This works, thanks. I basically thought of something like "xshift = x.initial + #1", and I was not sure how to input the default value in the formula.