# Parsing non-expandable commands like \small, using expl3

Tags: expl3, xparse, optional-arguments, gb4e, cgloss4e

Using `expl3` syntax, I want in my `\coolgloss` command to use as an optional argument one or several formatting commands such as `\small` and `\itshape`.

With a command like `\newcommand{\coolgloss}[3][\small\itshape]{text}{gloss}` I have no problems, but I specifically want to use `expl3` in order to have a split optional which includes the negative `raise` value for `\rule`.

It works if I only want to pass one command name (e.g. `small`) through `\csname...\endcsname`, but I want support for multiple commands (e.g. `\small\itshape`), and I want the arguments to be given with the backslash included.

Thus, the command must take a split optional argument, whose the second subargument (argument `#2`) is dedicated to the formatting:

```
\coolgloss[5,\small\itshape]{text}{gloss}
```

But when I input it, the `\small` command (not the `\itshape` one) triggers a `TeX capacity exceeded` error.

This has to be an issue with expansion and variable types, i.e. somewhere I should replace a `n` with some other type.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{gb4e}

\NewDocumentCommand{\coolglossaux}{mmmm}{%
    \renewcommand{\eachwordtwo}{\rule[-#1pt]{0pt}{0pt}#2}% !! #2 is the one !!
    \getwords(\lineone,\eachwordone)#3 \\%
    \getwords(\linetwo,\eachwordtwo)#4 \\%
    \loop\lastword{\eachwordone}{\lineone}{\wordone}%
    \lastword{\eachwordtwo}{\linetwo}{\wordtwo}%
    \global\setbox\gline=\hbox{\unhbox\gline
        \hskip\glossglue
        \vtop{\box\wordone
            \nointerlineskip
            \box\wordtwo
        }%
    }%
    \testdone
    \ifnotdone
    \repeat
    {\hskip -\glossglue}\unhbox\gline
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\coolgloss}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}omm}
{
    \my_xcoolgloss:nnnn #1 {#2} {#3}
}
\cs_new_protected:Nn \my_xcoolgloss:nnnn
{
    \__my_xcoolgloss:eenn
    { \tl_if_novalue:nTF { #1 } { 10 } { #1 } }
    { \tl_if_novalue:nTF { #2 } {} { #2 } }
    { #3 }
    { #4 }
}

\cs_set_eq:NN \__my_xcoolgloss:nnnn \coolglossaux
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__my_xcoolgloss:nnnn {ee}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    
    \coolgloss[5,\itshape]{I like \LaTeX}{I like \LaTeX}
    
    %\coolgloss[5,\small\itshape]{I like \LaTeX}{I like \LaTeX} => TeX capacity exceeded
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can't expand `\small` (you get the same error with just `\expanded{\small}`). You need to either protect `\small` or not try and expand it.

Comment: I understand,  `\small` is not expandable because in its definition, `\selectfont` has already expanded `\fontsize{}{}`.

Comment: The issue is actually a bit more subtle than that. `\itshape` and `\small` both ultimately call `\selectfont`, which is unexpandable since it calls `\def`. The difference is that `\itshape` is a `\protected` macro while `\small` is `\protect`'ed. `\protected` macros never expand (except with `\expandafter`) while `\protect`'ed macros only don't expand if they are used in certain LaTeX constructs (like `\protected@edef`). It's a fairly confusing topic, not at all helped by the confusing names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As MaxChernoff said, you can't expand `\small`. For this reason the following uses `\exp_not:n` for your two optional sub-arguments, so that the `\tl_if_novalue:nTF` tests are completely processed, but their results don't expand any further.

**EDIT:** I changed the auxiliary `\coolglossaux` to be defined `\protected` via `\@ifdefinable` and `\protected\def`. This might not be ideal as well, but unfortunately LaTeX2e has no good interface to `\protected` outside the `expl3` and `\NewDocumentCommand` routes. Also I've fixed a bug in the argument splitter if the optional argument isn't used at all.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{gb4e}

\makeatletter
% not perfect as well, but LaTeX2e itself has no good interface to `\protected`.
% The `\@ifdefinable` makes this behave like `\newcommand` even though we use
% a primitive `\def` for the definition.
\@ifdefinable{\coolglossaux}
    {%
        \protected\def\coolglossaux#1#2#3#4{%
            \renewcommand{\eachwordtwo}{\rule[-#1pt]{0pt}{0pt}#2}% !! #2 is the one !!
            \getwords(\lineone,\eachwordone)#3 \\%
            \getwords(\linetwo,\eachwordtwo)#4 \\%
            \loop\lastword{\eachwordone}{\lineone}{\wordone}%
            \lastword{\eachwordtwo}{\linetwo}{\wordtwo}%
            \global\setbox\gline=\hbox{\unhbox\gline
                \hskip\glossglue
                \vtop{\box\wordone
                    \nointerlineskip
                    \box\wordtwo
                }%
            }%
            \testdone
            \ifnotdone
            \repeat
            {\hskip -\glossglue}\unhbox\gline
        }
    }
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\coolgloss}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}omm}
{
    \tl_if_novalue:nTF {#1}
        { \my_xcoolgloss:nnnn {#1} {#1} {#2} {#3} }
        { \my_xcoolgloss:nnnn #1 {#2} {#3} }
}
\cs_new_protected:Nn \my_xcoolgloss:nnnn
{
    \__my_xcoolgloss:eenn
    { \tl_if_novalue:nTF { #1 } { 10 } { \exp_not:n {#1} } }
    { \tl_if_novalue:nTF { #2 } {} { \exp_not:n {#2} } }
    { #3 }
    { #4 }
}

\cs_set_eq:NN \__my_xcoolgloss:nnnn \coolglossaux
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__my_xcoolgloss:nnnn {ee}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    
    \coolgloss[5,\itshape]{I like \LaTeX}{I like \LaTeX}
    
    \coolgloss[5,\small\itshape]{I like \LaTeX}{I like \LaTeX} => TeX capacity exceeded
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: I see, so this was an expandability issue after all. I did not know of `exp_not:n`, many thanks.

Comment: @VincentKrebs Just a note: You shouldn't use `\NewDocumentCommand` for internals such as your auxiliary, there is some overhead to it, even if all arguments are just `m` or you're using no argument at all. Better to use a protected normal macro with 4 arguments in this case.

Comment: Really? Didn't know. I guess it makes sense since the *-DocumentCommand* part means it is intended for the body, not for low-level commands. I am following the model given to me through `egreg`'s kind answers here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/647169/262813 and here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/669975/262813.

Comment: @VincentKrebs imho, the `\cs_new_eq:NN` ... `\cs_generate_variant:Nn` approach makes sense if you want to access existing functions, but I'd not define a completely new function that's only ever used as an internal via `\NewDocumentCommand` (which seems to be the case for your `\coolglossaux`).

Comment: `\newcommand` doesn't define the macros protected, but your auxiliary should be, so no, not `\newcommand`. You don't need `expl3` to split your argument, but the full expansion to use the defaults via the `\cs_generate_variant:Nn` route is much more handy than doing that by hand.

Comment: @VincentKrebs note that the code above has a bug due to a strange design decision: Argument processors (like `\SplitArgument`) are not used on `o` types if the optional argument was not used.

Comment: @VincentKrebs `\DeclareRobustCommand` doesn't define `\protected` but using LaTeX2e's older `\protect` mechanism.

Comment: If "LaTeX2e has no good interface to `\protected`", why not use LaTeX3? I mean `expl3` (but something other than `\NewDocumentCommand`, which you said was not appropriate for internals).

Comment: @VincentKrebs because LaTeX3's only sensible interface to `\protected` for internals is `\cs_new_protected:Npn` or `\cs_new_protected:Nn` in the `expl3` language, and then we mix `expl3` code with LaTeX2e code which is also not-so-good style, but I have no definitive answer here, you could use `\cs_new_protected:Npn` instead of the `\@ifdefinable` and `\protected\def`.

Answer (score 1):

*Obligatory self-advertisement since key=value solutions were mentioned: `expkv`*

An implementation with a key=value solution and smartish unknown-key handling (literal numeric input will be assumed to be `space`, else it's assumed to be `style` -- if this is unwanted remove the block in `\makeatletter...\makeatother`) using the `expkv` family:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expkv-unravel}

% has to be loaded before `gb4e` as the latter changes the category code of ^
\usepackage{expkv-cs}

% defining the key=value interface
\NewDocumentCommand\coolgl{O{}mm}
  {\coolglKV{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\ekvcSplitAndForward\coolglKV\coolglossaux
  {%
    space = 10,
    style = \small
  }

% defining a special rule how to handle unknown keys without a value
\makeatletter
\ekvdefunknownNoVal{\string\coolglKV}
  {%
    \coolglKV@ifnumber{#1}% will be true only for literal numerical input
      {\ekvcPass\coolglKV{space}}%
      {\ekvcPass\coolglKV{style}}%
        {#2}%
  }
% defining a smartish parser
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \coolglKV@ifempty \tl_if_empty:nTF
\ExplSyntaxOff
\protected\long\def\coolglKV@ifnumber#1%
  {%
    \begingroup
      \afterassignment\coolglKV@ifnumber@aux
      \count\z@=\iffalse{\fi0#1}%
  }
\protected\def\coolglKV@ifnumber@aux
  {%
    \endgroup
    \expandafter\coolglKV@ifempty\expandafter{\iffalse}\fi
  }
\makeatother

\protected\def\coolglossaux#1#2#3#4{%
    \renewcommand{\eachwordtwo}{\rule[-#1pt]{0pt}{0pt}#2}% !! #2 is the one !!
    \getwords(\lineone,\eachwordone)#3 \\%
    \getwords(\linetwo,\eachwordtwo)#4 \\%
    \loop\lastword{\eachwordone}{\lineone}{\wordone}%
    \lastword{\eachwordtwo}{\linetwo}{\wordtwo}%
    \global\setbox\gline=\hbox{%
        \unhbox\gline\hskip\glossglue\vtop{%
            \box\wordone\nointerlineskip\box\wordtwo
        }%
    }%
    \testdone
    \ifnotdone
    \repeat
    {\hskip -\glossglue}\unhbox\gline
}

% evil package changing catcodes in the preamble... :P
\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}
\coolgl[style=\itshape\bfseries\footnotesize,space=30]{%
i try something very long in order to get two lines this is so wonderful and now you see the vertical space optional argument is perfectly working}{%
i try something very long in order to get two lines this is so wonderful and now you see the vertical space optional argument is perfectly working}

\coolgl[\itshape\bfseries\footnotesize,60]{%
i try something very long in order to get two lines this is so wonderful and now you see the vertical space optional argument is perfectly working}{%
i try something very long in order to get two lines this is so wonderful and now you see the vertical space optional argument is perfectly working}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @VincentKrebs `\^^` is not a macro, `\^^@` is (`^^` is special, it changes the next character as a rot64, making `^^@` the character code 0, but that only works if `^` has category code math-superscript, which is changed by `gb4e`).

Comment: @VincentKrebs you did nothing wrong, I just used a feature of `expkv` that is in the current development version, forgetting I didn't yet publish that particular feature. You can get the up-to-date version [on GitLab](https://gitlab.com/islandoftex/texmf/expkv-bundle), or just wait for a few days (maybe a week) until I release it... The current version doesn't support picking up the un-`\detokenize`d key names of unknown keys, hence using them for formatting stuff won't work with it.

Comment: @VincentKrebs don't bother, I'll publish them in a few days or so... Btw. installing it manually is pretty easy: Clone the repository, then run `l3build install` on the command line inside the main directory.

Comment: @VincentKrebs Exactly as I've written, open a command line in that directory (if you're on Windows: While being in the directory with the Explorer hold Shift and right-click on a blank space, then select "open in command line" (or something like that, no idea how it's translated)), then type `l3build install` and hit <Enter>. The `l3build` program should be part of your LaTeX-distribution.

Comment: @VincentKrebs if you want to later remove the package run `l3build uninstall`, afterwards you can delete the folder.

Comment: I see you released `expkv-bundle` yesterday on ctan ;) cool ;)) (I had not managed to install it manually because I got an error `l3build-unpack.lua:87: attempt to index a nil value`. By the way I downloaded the ctan file but build.lua is missing from the .zip. (and expkv-bundle still does not appear in the MikTeX database)

Comment: @VincentKrebs give the poor MikTeX maintainer a few days :) And yes, CTAN-uploads don't include the build scripts...

Comment: Thought that was auto!

Comment: @VincentKrebs depends. If I upload the thing to CTAN it takes roughly 24h to be on the mirrors. It is a new package (earlier I uploaded the packages individually, now it's bundled into one upload), so no automatic routine for TeXLive and MikTeX maintainers, afaik.

Comment: Anyway congratulations, this is an amazing package, now unified.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it could come in handy to other people, to show that, with a `key=value` system, no such issues arise.

Note that it is most often the better approach in many aspects.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{gb4e}

\protected\def\coolglossaux#1#2#3#4{%
    \renewcommand{\eachwordtwo}{\rule[-#1pt]{0pt}{0pt}#2}% !! #2 is the one !!
    \getwords(\lineone,\eachwordone)#3 \\%
    \getwords(\linetwo,\eachwordtwo)#4 \\%
    \loop\lastword{\eachwordone}{\lineone}{\wordone}%
    \lastword{\eachwordtwo}{\linetwo}{\wordtwo}%
    \global\setbox\gline=\hbox{%
        \unhbox\gline\hskip\glossglue\vtop{%
            \box\wordone\nointerlineskip\box\wordtwo
        }%
    }%
    \testdone
    \ifnotdone
    \repeat
    {\hskip -\glossglue}\unhbox\gline
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\coolgl}{O{}mm}
{
    \group_begin:
    \keys_set:nn { coolgl } { #1 }
    \coolgl:VVnn
    \coolgl_space
    \coolgl_style
    { #2 }
    { #3 }
    \group_end:
}
\keys_define:nn { coolgl }
{
    space.tl_set:N = \coolgl_space,
    style.tl_set:N = \coolgl_style,
    space.initial:n = 10,
    style.initial:n = \small,
}

\cs_set_eq:NN \coolgl:nnnn \coolglossaux

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \coolgl:nnnn { VV }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
        
\coolgl[space=30,style=\itshape\bfseries\footnotesize]{%
i try something very long in order to get two lines this is so wonderful and now you see the vertical space optional argument is perfectly working}{%
i try something very long in order to get two lines this is so wonderful and now you see the vertical space optional argument is perfectly working}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's indeed much better than multiple optional arguments.

Comment: It's interesting to know how to do both and compare them (even maybe in some cases to have two versions of the same auxiliary, like here `\coolgloss` and `\coolgl`). For example, I'm happy to know about the `\exp_not:n{x}` command. The `expl3` syntax seems to be powerful.

Comment: @VincentKrebs `expl3` is indeed very powerful as it provides a very well thought out set of powerful functions and conventions. With it TeX coding feels more like programming in a high level programming language than in a strange eccentric macro expansion language (though I definitely love the quirks of that strange eccentric macro expansion language).